Commands to find previous/next occurence of a string on a ipynb notebook on vscode
I know the following commands on Vscode to find a previous/next occurence of a string on an editor :
    { "key": "ctrl+n", "command": "editor.action.nextMatchFindAction" },
    { "key": "ctrl+p", "command": "editor.action.previousMatchFindAction" }

But these are not working on an ipynb notebook : I checked with the Keyboard Shortcuts Troubleshooting, the commands are well triggered but the previous/next occurence is not being focused.
My question : are there any commands for that for ipynb notebooks ?
If not, is there any workaround to bind that with CTRL+n and CTRL+p keys ?

Maybe there isn't a command for this? Notebook editors in VS Code have their own find widget implementation (see also Why is find and replace in Notebooks in VS Code different than in text documents? Are there ways to make them more similar?), and looking at the code for findBtn, I don't see any command binding. You could raise a feature-request issue ticket for there to be a command for this, or for it to integrate with the existing commands like editor.action.nextMatchFindAction.

If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to it, or notify me in it with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.

starball : thanks for your time. Here is the issue on vscode : https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/214213 and another one on vscodevim I raised earlier : https://github.com/VSCodeVim/Vim/issues/9049.
